# Bokeh Title Spacing

Tags: python, heatmap, bokeh, spacing

i'm looking for a way to reduce the spacing in a `Bokeh` plot, this is a `HeatMap` that I've made in `Bokeh`:

[image]

I want the title to be more close to the plot but I haven't found the way to do this. ¿Any ideas on how to solve this?

Here is my code:

```
from bokeh.io import output_file
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.models import (
    ColumnDataSource,
    HoverTool,
    LinearColorMapper
)
from bokeh.plotting import figure

output_file('test.html', mode='inline')

source = ColumnDataSource(RandomData)
TOOLS = "hover,save"

# Creating the Figure
HM = figure(title="HeatMap", 
       x_range=[str(i) for i in range(1,32)], 
       y_range=[str(i) for i in range(1643,1600,-1)]+[str(i) for i in range(6043,6000,-1)],
       x_axis_location="above", plot_width=500, plot_height=970,
       tools=TOOLS, toolbar_location='right')

# Figure Styling
HM.grid.grid_line_color = None

HM.axis.axis_line_color = None
HM.axis.major_tick_line_color = None
HM.axis.major_label_text_font_size = "7pt"
HM.axis.major_label_text_alpha = 0.5
HM.axis.major_label_standoff = 0

HM.toolbar.logo = None

HM.title.text_font = 'century gothic'
HM.title.text_font_size = '14pt'
HM.title.text_font_style = 'normal'
HM.title.text_color = '#6a94d8'
HM.title_location = 'below'
HM.title.align = 'center'

# Color Mapping
mapper = LinearColorMapper(palette='Blues9', low=RandomData.Total.max(),
         high=RandomData.Total.min())

# Creating the Glyphs
HM.rect(x='XData', y="YData", width=1, height=1,source=source,
         fill_color={'field': 'Total','transform': mapper},line_alpha=0.05)

show(HM)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show your work.

Comment: Just to make sure @Soviut's IMO rightful comment is not misunderstood (I did that on first glance): This is not a code review site, so what did you look up as concepts or which did bring you closest to your goal is missing (not some source code). bokeh has a real nice and easy to navigate reference guide, just start with plotting figure and work your way upstream to the general `Plot` class to find the attribute `title_location` - and maybe write an answer yourself or amend the question.